# org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span" getting this error in katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

using katalon studio Tried to select a dropdown value display erorr like Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.UnexpectedTagNameException: Element should have been "select" but was "span"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHdLY.png)
please get me out of this

Comment: Please share the HTML of the element in question, and your code. The error suggests you are targeting a "span" HTML element instead of a "select" element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.